# JAR file doesn't run exactly like when running project from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

This is my first post here.

I am running into a weird problem that i don't really understand.

I have developed a Java desktop app using Eclipse, and when running it from Eclipse all the features seem to work. But when i export and run the jar file, the execution is not the same.

The jar file don't execute these two lines of code :

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"I'm here");
LireExcel lierexcel = new LireExcel(this.matrivule,this.nomOAC,this.lblDate,this.poste);
lierexcel.traiterFichier(lierexcel);
```

I've added the message dialog to see where the execution stops... it does not execute the method `traiterFichier()`

EDIT:

When i redirect the java error stream to a txt file i find this :

```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook
    at control.EcouteurBoutonGenererRapport.actionPerformed(EcouteurBoutonGenererRapport.java:124)
    at view.CreerRapport$1.btnGnrerActionPerformed(CreerRapport.java:108)
    at view.CreerRapport$1.actionPerformed(CreerRapport.java:102)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 39 more
```

I don't understand why this don't happen when running the project from Eclipse..

Comment: `LireExcel` for everyone means `ReadExcel` so I guess the file can't be reach. Edit : Don't expect everyone to understand french ;) provide more information, see [ask] please.

Comment: We can't answer if you don't precise where these lines are executed... Are they in your main? In a class? Do your program takes parameters?

Comment: If you export your project, it could simply be that your program doesn't find your excel. Is the code you showed in a try catch? Do you check if your file was read? Once again, just from these lines it isn't possible (imo) to provide an answer

Comment: We probably need to see the code of LireExcel#traiterFichier, also what do you mean by not the same?

Comment: When you run your Jar from the command line, redirect console output to a file (how to do that depends on the system you are on) and look if there are any exceptions thrown. Note that on windows, you normally won't see any console output when starting your program from the shell using `javaw`.

Comment: These two lines of codes are executed in an actionPerformed method (When the user clicks button).. And it creates an instance of the class "LireExcel" (ReadExcel) and the last line calls a method "traiterFichier" within this class. I've put an Message dialog in the begining of "traiterFichier" method, it don't show up. 

The code works fine when i run it from Eclipse.